# primefaces datatable rowEditor not working for p:selectManyMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have implemented primefaces roweditor for components like inputtext,autocomplete . I am trying to implement for selectmanymenu but could not get the result. If i use cell editor then i need to use input and output value should refer the same . Here selectmanymenu value would be the list not a single variable. So i am not sure how to handle it.

I would like know the proper implementation of p:selectManyMenu with p:cellEditor. I am not sure that we have option to do this also.

I have searched in stackoverflow as well as in google, did not get any answers for this.

Please help me out.

Below is the code details

```
<p:dataTable
    value="#{projectViewBean.projectListToEdit}"
    editable="true" var="proj" id="editProjLst">
     <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{projectEntryBean.onEdit}"/>
     <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{projectEntryBean.onRowEditInit}"></p:ajax>
<p:column headerText="Project Status" id="sts">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{proj.projectStatus}"></p:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu
                    value="#{proj.projectStatus}"
                    id="pjstval">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{projectEntryBean.projectStatusList}"
                        id="pjstlst" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Phase" id="dbphase">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{proj.projectPhaseValue}"></p:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:autoComplete
                    completeMethod="#{projectEntryBean.autoSearchProjectPhase}"
                    value="#{proj.projectPhaseValue}"
                    dropdown="true" scrollHeight="200" emptyMessage="No Phase Found"
                    minQueryLength="1" forceSelection="true"></p:autoComplete>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
<p:column headerText="Project Manager" id="pjtmgr">
        <p:cellEditor id="pm">
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{projectEntryBean.pjtView.projectUserList}"></p:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectManyMenu
                    value="#{proj.projectManager}"
                    id="projectmanagerval">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{projectEntryBean.pjtView.projectUserList}"
                        id="pmlst" />
                </p:selectManyMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
<p:column style="width:32px">
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: please explain ***but could not get the result*** in words or through screenshot

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar, Once i selected 2 values from the selectonemenu, it will be saved in DB Later when i want to retreive the same value in the format of datatable with row editor, selectmanymenu component has to show the value which is stored , but here it is not showing because facet output is label and facet input is list

Comment: @rao, Thanks for ur link. I always used to refer it. But there i see only for selectonemenu but no option for selectmanymenu

Comment: @RadhamaniMuthusamy please show project entity and its children in question.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar, Its all related to many pojo class and db . To test for you, just have a list of users in the arraylist and assign to f:selectitems and declare the variable which is of list to the value of p:selectManymenu. Please check and if you want me to write and give the same also fine. I feel this might be related to row editor. While editing other componenents, the saved value is displaying but for selectmanymenu the saved value is not displayed.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue. Open an issue here --> http://www.primefaces.org/issuetracker

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar, Thank you so much for your time to check this issue. I am trying to create an account as i have account only for primefaces forum but not able to create it. So cant post this issue in primefaces issue tracker  and even tried here also  but no option to create a  issue https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list?can=1&q=roweditor&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+TargetVersion+Reporter+Owner+Summary&y=5000&cells=tiles

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar, Finally i got the solution and its working fine. i have posted the answer as well. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i am able to achieve it by using converter. It might be helpful for someone. Please see the solution

```
<p:column headerText="Project Manager" id="pjtmgr">
    <p:cellEditor id="pm">
        <f:facet name="output">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{proj.projectManager}">
           <f:converter converterId="vendorConverter"></f:converter>
          </p:outputLabel>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectManyMenu
                value="#{proj.projectManager}"
                id="projectmanagerval">
                <f:selectItems value="#{projectEntryBean.pjtView.projectUserList}"
                    id="pmlst" />
            </p:selectManyMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```